# Wait for a Subscription and a Promise in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

I'm new to Angular 4, so I accept that I may be better off changing my approach.

What I have is this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
            var id = +params.get('id');
            return this.service.getOne(id);
        }).subscribe(data => {
            if (data.clientID === 0) {
                data.clientID = +this.route.snapshot.queryParams["parentId"];
            }
            this.model = data;
        },); // Subscription

    this.lookupService.getList("clients").then(data => {
        this.clients = data;
    }); // Promise
}
```

On the client-side, I need to make another server call, but only when I have data from both of the calls above. In other words, I need the `Subscription` to complete (well, not complete but set the value) and the `Promise` to complete.

Is there something like a `Promise.all` that would work to also ensure `this.model` has been set in the `Subscription` call?

EDIT:
I could run these in series, but for performance reasons, I want to run them in parallel.

EDIT 2:
The `Promise` was intended to load lookup data to populate a dropdown only once. The `Subscription` was intended to change the main model on each change of "id" in the URL .

Comment: So `lookupService.getList()` should run only once. `service.getOne()` should run every time a new param arrives right?  Ok, what about the 3rd call? You said it should wait for the other two to produce, but what about after the first production?  Should the 3rd call be made only once or every time a new param arrives?

Comment: @BeetleJuice I've simplified the third call to just run a local filter function, but it needs to run along with each new param, after `service.getOne()` updates.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer and provided a demo. If you settle on a better solution, please teach it to us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Observable.forkJoin`, which is equivalent to `Promise.all`.

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
            var id = +params.get('id');
            return this.service.getOne(id);
        }), Observable.fromPromise(this.lookupService.getList("clients")))
        .subscribe((arrayOfResults) => {
             [firstCallResult, secondCallResult] = arrayOfResults;
             this.model = firstCallResult;
        });
```

**EDIT:**

To fulfill the part about updating parameters, we can use the `Observable.combineLatest` operator:

[About Observable.combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

Since it emits whenever one of the source observables emits, the subscribe block will be executed. Since the other observable is from a promise it will complete and not emit more values so this.lookupService.getList() will not be called again.

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.route.paramMap
            .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
                var id = +params.get('id');
                return this.service.getOne(id);
            }), Observable.fromPromise(this.lookupService.getList("clients")))
            .subscribe((arrayOfResults) => {
                 [firstCallResult, secondCallResult] = arrayOfResults;
                 this.model = firstCallResult;
                 // do whatever else is needed
            });
```

Comment: Our "service layer" has dozens of objects returning Promises (like in the angular.io tutorial) and changing that would have global impacts. However, if this is the only way, then I suppose I need to do it.

Comment: @KevinWelsh see my edit. You can use `Observable.fromPromise()` to convert a promise to an observable.

Comment: Nice. `combineLatest()` is the right operator for this I think

Comment: @Matsura, `combineLatest()` works very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `.zip()` on the promise and the model-fetching observable. It will output an array of results that you can use to populate local class properties. At this point you can call your 3rd function (the local filter). Once the promise completes, so will `.zip`, so this chain has only one output.
2. Once `.zip()` completes, listen to new route parameters and fetch corresponding models. As they arrive, set your local class property and run your local filter
3. Subscribe to trigger the whole chain.

   ```
   ngOnInit(){
       // Will run getOne() with every new parameter
       let getModelForParam = this.route.paramMap.switchMap(
           params => this.service.getOne(+params.get('id'))
       ).share();

       // Zip will wait for both below to produce, then output an array of results
       // and complete (since getList() promise completes after one call)
       Observable.zip(
           this.lookupService.getList('clients'),
           getModelForParam
       ).do(results => { // capture results in order of .zip() arguments
           this.clients = results[0];
           this.model = results[1];
           this.localFilter();// call the filter
       }).concat( // this part executes once .zip() completes
           getModelForParam // continue fetching models for new params
       ).subscribe(model => {
           this.model = model;
           this.localFilter();
       })
   }
   ```

[**Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/jokonijeye/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: I believe `switchMap` doesn't complete because the component can be reused, and you can't use `take(1)` since you will loose all following updates to params if the component gets reused

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi Interesting problem. I think you're right. Since this is likely meant to be run each time a new param is emitted, we shouldn't stop after 1 result. A better approach is to use `zip`. It will also make the calls in parallel, but emit only once both responses arrive.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi actually now that I think about it, the OP has one of the results coming as a promise resolution which means one-and-done. So if a requirement is that the 3rd call be made after the results from the first two arrive, the 3rd call will only occur once (because a promise only resolves  once). Thus in practice I don't see the difference between `forkJoin / take(1)` and `zip`

Comment: Thanks @BeetleJuice. I actually do need future notifications, though, on the paramMap. But I do not need to reload the  `this.lookupService.getList("clients")` each time. Also, I tried your code sample, and the code in the ellipses of the `this.route.paramMap.switchMap('...')` never runs. I added these 2 to the top of the file:
`import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/zip';`

Comment: @KevinWelsh, so do you want to run `this.lookupService.getList` only once but `this.service.getOne(id)` every time the param changes and then contcatenate the results and emit new item every time params changes?

Comment: @KevinWelsh I've updated the answer to meet your clarifications.

Comment: @BeetleJuice I have edited my answer to incorporate the future notifications from the route observable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.lookupService.getList("clients").then(data => {
    this.clients = data;
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        var id = +params.get('id');
        return this.service.getOne(id);
    }).subscribe(data => {
        if (data.clientID === 0) {
            data.clientID = +this.route.snapshot.queryParams["parentId"];
        }
        this.model = data;
==>Call ur method here!!!
    },); /

}); // Promise
```

Comment: I'll update the question, but I don't want to run these server calls in series.